# October CMS - Permission admin user to edit only one record

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

If I have a list of houses in the administration.
I want to make it possible for every admin user to edit the house I allow, and only see it in the list.

Is that possible?
In what direction to go?

Thank you very much.

Comment: October gives out of the box permission for the `whole action` not individual records so you need to add this functionality manually i guess, `mm table` storing exit relation to given record and when use try to edit record `check permission` if allowed then allow him edit `if not` redirect or show error. same goes for listing

Comment: Tnx. But don't know where to start. I meant first do a relation between house and user. Eg. When you are adding or edit house, you heve options to select one user, from users list. And after that in backend when list of houses is render i check if house have relation with login user/editor. What you think about this approach?

Comment: yes that also work, mean to say you need to make it custom how you do its up to you, october don't provide it so. AND yes you are doing correct just check relation if it has allowed user/ related user let him do stuff other wise show error.